# How to run oauth2_proxy on ec2 instance for Kibana login

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, proxy, oauth-2.0, kibana

How can I start the oauth2_proxy on my ECs instance? I finished the configuration but I can't get it to run.

Comment: You'll need to show us some error messages.

Comment: I don't have any, cause I'm not able to start the server.

Comment: Define "server."  Do you mean the entire instance fails to boot?  Or the server daemon ("service") won't start?